# Chinese Unicode issue?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

From this website http://engine.data.cnzz.com/main.php?s=engine&uv=&st=2014-03-01&et=2014-03-31

```
<tr class="list03" onclick="showMen1(9);" style="cursor:pointer;">
<td id="e_9" class="qh_one">百度汇总</td>
```

I'm scraping the text and trying to get `百度汇总`

but when I `r.encoding = 'utf-8'` the result is `�ٶȻ���`

if I don't use `utf-8` the result is `°Ù¶È»ã×Ü`

Comment: The page uses GBK, not UTF-8.

Comment: how do you figure that out? could you show me please. I see `utf-8` everywhere in the html.

Comment: @jason_cant_code: line 6 is `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb2312" />` The only places with "utf-8" on the page are declaring the encoding of imported javascript.

Comment: Got it. So I look for `meta content` and `charset`? so what should be the right encoding? `r.encoding='gb2312'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server doesn't tell you anything helpful in the response headers, but the HTML page itself contains:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb2312" />
```

[GB2312](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GB2312) is a variable-width encoding, like UTF-8. The page lies however; it in actual fact uses [GBK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GBK), an extension to GB2312.

You can decode it with GBK just fine:

```
>>> len(r.content.decode('gbk'))
44535
>>> u'百度汇总' in r.content.decode('gbk')
True
```

Decoding with `gb2313` fails:

```
>>> r.content.decode('gb2312')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'gb2312' codec can't decode bytes in position 26367-26368: illegal multibyte sequence
```

but since GBK is a superset of GB2313, it should always be safe to use the former even when the latter is specified.

If you are using `requests`, then setting `r.encoding` to `gb2312` works because `r.text` uses `replace` when handling decode errors:

```
content = str(self.content, encoding, errors='replace')
```

so the decoding error when using GB2312 is masked for those codepoints only defined in GBK.

Note that BeautifulSoup can do the decoding all by itself; it'll find the `meta` header:

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
WARNING:root:Some characters could not be decoded, and were replaced with REPLACEMENT CHARACTER.
```

The warning is caused by the GBK codepoints being used while the page claims to use GB2312.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Good stuff.